# Как переделать flowtextview?

Tags: android, java

Как переделать `FlowTextView`?

Я уже устал, создаю 3 тему с подобной проблемой, никто толком ответить не может, что мне сделать. Я новичок и пытаюсь изменить размер текста, но не получается у меня ну никак, и читал и гуглил - не доходит, не понимаю, как реализовать. Как же быть-то? Может, кто готовый `FlowText` скинет, я к проекту добавлю, и все... Все равно не понимаю, как переделывать такие вещи... XML редактировать не умею.

Comment: *Мне жалко пользователей вашей будущей программы ._.*

А теперь по теме: что за FlowTextView и где вы его откопали? Какими именно способами пытались изменить размер текста?

Comment: @SuperCreeper, 
http://kuznetsow.com/?p=144
hashcode.ru/questions/375912/java-кастомный-контроллер-на-канве
Вот ссылки все которые надыбал,

Вот сам FlowTextView https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@xTIGRx](/users/22339/xtigrx)](/users/22339/xtigrx), поглядел на исходники. `FlowTextView.java`, строки `90`-`92` — именно они вызывают у меня подозрение. В методе `readAttrs` (строка `105`) действительно читается значение из xml атрибута `android:textSize`, но читается позже, чем устанавливается (строка `84`). Попробуйте перенести строки `90`-`92` в самое начало метода `init`, по идее, должно заработать. Если вы используете *jar* библиотеку, то советую вместо неё импортировать *проект* библиотеки, чтобы была возможность менять её код.

P.S. Если я оказался неправ со своим подозрением, то пусть меня поправят более знающие люди. :)

Comment: @SuperCreeper, дак  у него вообще нет метода android:textSize

Comment: @xTIGRx это не метод, а атрибут. И он будет работать, если его использовать (если предварительно сделать то, что сказал @SuperCreeper. Я еще вчера создал ишью у него на гитхабе)

Comment: @metalurgus, нашел на гитхабе, а вы можете в jar переделать а то, когда я подключаю проект, у меня вылетает прога сразу, с jar такого нет.

Вот http://pastebin.com/KtN8UdZy. Говорит, что я неправильно в xml пишу и типа нет класса такого...

Comment: @xTIGRx готов поспорить на бутылку вискаря - то что вы делаете, можно сделать гораздо более простым (читай лучшим) способом. Какие-то кастомные вьюхи, какие-то бажёные аттрибуты, какие-то левые джарники, десятки активити с утечками памяти в придачу...

Comment: @argamidon, я понимаю, но я создавал тему чтобы мне идею подкинули а никто с таким не сталкивался. А мне все то надо отобразить картинку слева и текст который будет обтекать картинку и все....нет ничего другого.